# Can the shellshock bug be expoloited to run a command as a privileged user?

Tags: bash, shellshock

I am curious to know if the following command could be executed on a system/server with the Shellshock bug:

```
curl -H "User-Agent: () { :; }; sudo /bin/eject" http://example.com/
```

(This code is an elaborated version of an example here: http://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/)

From what I understand the bug would allow one to inject code into the system but not necessarily execute code with elevated privileges. If this is not possible is there another way that code could be injected to give a hacker root privileges?

No examples necessary, I am simply curious as to the extent of damage this bug could potentially cause.

**I have no malicious intent, I ask out of curiosity.

Comment: I don't believe there's any special opportunity to do privilege elevation -- the problem is that you'd be able to execute script code at the privilege level of whatever bash is launched with.  That's pretty bad.   If that account has sudo privileges, then yes it would be root-ish.  But that's probably a rare server misconfiguration in the first place.

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/q/68552 (Note that the accepted answer there is wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 curl -H "User-Agent: () { :; }; sudo /bin/eject" http://example.com/
```

Wouldn't work because it couldn't find `sudo`.

```
 curl -H "User-Agent: () { :; }; /usr/bin/sudo /bin/eject" http://example.com/
```

would manage to invoke `sudo`, but unless the administrator has configured `sudo` to allow the user running the web server to run any command as `root` (which would be the most unwise thing to do), that can't do much.

Even if the remote server allowed the web server user to run a particular command as `root`, first, you'd need to guess which it is, and then even if it were a `bash` script, the HTTP_USER_AGENT environment variable would not be passed to it even if `sudo` were configured with `env_reset` disabled because `sudo` always blacklists the variables whose content starts with `()`.

Though some scenarii can be imagined, there is no *common* way for shellshock to be used for local privilege escalation. See [this answer on security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/68852/16243) for more details.

Comment: I suspected this to be the case. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!